# How to set up postfix to relay outbound mail only?

Tags: email, postfix

I have a postfix/dovecot server in Linode. However many times my outgoing mail is being rejected because Linodes IP's are on blacklists.

To solve this issue I signed up to Amazon lightsail and created myself a CentOS server. I plan to set this up as a relay and have my Linode server relay mail through it. I'm fairly sure Amazon IP's will not be on any blacklists

This should be fairly simple to set up, but I'm just looking for a few pointers to get started. The Amazon server should only accept relayed mail via the Linode server and should request authentication. Could someone point to the configuration directives I'm looking for?

Comment: *I'm fairly sure Amazon IP's will not be on any blacklists* I have bad news for you... While there are IP block blocklists, most blocking happens because you haven't set up DNS and your mail server to sufficiently convince other mail servers you're not just a hijacked or free tier spam server. *This should be fairly simple to set up* I found it pretty intense to learn what GMail and Microsoft Outlook servers expect of your server (SPF, DMARC, the whole DNS setup)

Comment: Seriously? Darn.. well for now at least the IP I've been assigned is okay. I'd still like to set this up and perhaps use something like SendGrid if it becomes a problem later.
SPF DMARC and DNS are all accurate on my current Linode mail server.